# Lost Access to Site Collection

Tags: 2010, site-collection

I have a content database with multiple site collections. Out of nowhere(as far as I am concerned) two site collections became inaccessible. I can't browse them(server or client), I can't delete them(when I select them trough the UI the selection returns empty).

I am a little lost in where to start here. Detach/attach database? Restore?

Edit: I did this query in the content database:

```
select * from sites
```

And it returned the expected number of site collections, but the two that are inaccessible are missing the field FullUrl

Doing this in powershell solved it:

```
$db = get-SpContentDatabase –identity $id
$db.RefreshSitesInConfigurationDatabase()
```

I will leave the question open though, as I am not sure what causes this. Any hint would be appreciated. Also, for what I understand, the above command maps the site collections in a content database again, right?

Comment: are you by chance on 2010? i'm having the same issue there. only solution i found was to spin up a new web app and attach the content db there. [well i did find a solution to fix the original site but forgot to take notes]

Comment: I actually resolved the issue by using the following command on powershell: 
$db = get-SpContentDatabase –identity $id
$db.RefreshSitesInConfigurationDatabase()

Comment: thanks for responding!  we'll give it a go--it's a dev server.